# Is it possible to have two on_reaction_add(reaction, user) client.event or is there another way for those two to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

After making a working discord bot, I encountered a problem when I made the commands. In my commands, I made a lot of "on_reaction_add" functions. I tried to change the on_reaction_add functions to something else like on_react_add but, the command won't work. It'd either work for the other and for the other it doesn't. Is there a way to actually have both commands work?

on_reaction_add for the first command: [the one that doesn't work]

```
@client.event
async def reaction_add(reaction, user):
    await bot_events.on_reaction_add(reaction, user)
```

in case needed; the bot_events.on_reaction_add code

```
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

    if user.bot:
        return
    if user.id not in players:
        return
    emoji = reaction.emoji
    await reaction.remove(user)

    if reaction.message != players[user.id]['game']:
        return

    if emoji == "⬅️":
        players[user.id]['dir'] = "left"
    if emoji == "➡️":
        players[user.id]['dir'] = "right"
    if emoji == "⬇️":
        players[user.id]['dir'] = "down"
    if emoji == "⬆️":
        players[user.id]['dir'] = "up"
```

the other command's on_reaction_add

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    global h_movement
    global rotation_pos
    if user != client.user:
        msg = reaction.message
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶": #Play button pressed
            print('User pressed play')
            await reset_game()
            await msg.remove_reaction("❌", client.user) #Remove delete
            embed = discord.Embed(description=format_board_as_str(), color=embed_colour)
            await msg.remove_reaction("▶", user)
            await msg.remove_reaction("▶", client.user)
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)
            await msg.add_reaction("⬅") #Left
            await msg.add_reaction("⬇") #Down
            await msg.add_reaction("➡") #Right
            await msg.add_reaction("") #Rotate
            await msg.add_reaction("❌") #Stop game
            starting_shape = get_random_shape()
            await run_game(msg, starting_shape)

        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬅": #Left button pressed
            print('Left button pressed')
            h_movement = -1 #move 1 left
            await msg.remove_reaction("⬅", user)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "➡": #Right button pressed
            print('Right button pressed')
            h_movement = 1 #move +1 right
            await msg.remove_reaction("➡", user)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⬇": #Down button pressed
            print('Down button pressed')
            global down_pressed
            down_pressed = True
            await msg.remove_reaction("⬇", user)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "": #Rotate clockwise button pressed
            print('Rotate clockwise button pressed')
            global rotate_clockwise
            rotate_clockwise = True
            if rotation_pos < 3:
                rotation_pos += 1
            else:
                rotation_pos = 0 #go back to original pos
            await msg.remove_reaction("", user)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "❌": 
            await reset_game()
            await msg.delete()
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await message.edit(content="")
```

Comment: You can define how many ever event listeners you would like to, if the name and decorator is valid, all of them will be called on event.

Comment: @Sandy How do I fix it that both the event listeners with the `on_reaction_add` work? Sometimes the other one works and sometimes the other doesn't. The other part of the code has no problem, just the `on_reaction_add` part because when I try to test it out, the reaction emojis don't work the way I expect them to work. I have two `on_reaction_add` client events in the same file and I don't know how to fix it so, that two of the events work.

Comment: print something in both the event listeners, if it's not being printed two times, then there is a problem, otherwise it is with the code within the listener function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an event two times, you can do so in different [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cogs#cogs)